# Reloading a page with WKWebView always returns a cached version of the previous page

Tags: ios, webkit, wkwebview

Everything is in the title:

I have a `WKWebView` and when I try to reload the current page ( either with `reload`, `reloadFromOrigin` methods or by loading a request with the current url ( and ignoring local and remote cached data )), I always get a cached version of the previous page.

I tried on several websites on both my app, `Safari` and `Firefox` and it's always the same. So I guess there's a bug with `WebKit` but can you guys think about any workaround ?

I was thinking about loading an empty page before triggering a reload ( so I'd have to cache the previous url etc... )